# How can I combine these two queries?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have two tables:

- Table A, for record orders:

  Columns: OrderId, Amount, Good, Details, UserId and more
- Table B, for record order status, for example: paid, shipped, refund.

  Columns: OrderId, Status, UpdateTime

My current query:

First:

```
select * from TABLE_A
```

to get order list.

And then, get each order's status:

```
select top 1 * 
from TABLE_B 
where OrderId = orderid 
order by UpdateTime desc
```

How can I combine these two queries into a single one, and the result data in all-in-one? Thank you.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Probably more looking at `CROSS APPLY` here, if the OP wants to retain the `TOP 1`.

Comment: yes, i want each order record links to a order status which is latest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could join TABLE_A on a sub-query with TABLE_B.
And use a TOP 1 WITH TIES in combination with a ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER.

```
SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM TABLE_A AS A
JOIN 
(
  SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
  FROM TABLE_B
  ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Orderid ORDER BY UpdateTime DESC)
) AS B ON (B.OrderId = A.Orderid)
```

Or even without sub-query.

**Example snippet:**

```
declare @TABLE_A table (Orderid int);
declare @TABLE_B table (ID int identity(1,1), Orderid int, UpdateTime datetime);
insert into @TABLE_A (Orderid) values (1001),(1002);
insert into @TABLE_B (Orderid, UpdateTime) values 
 (1001,GetDate()-5),(1001,GetDate()-4),(1001,GetDate()-3)
,(1002,GetDate()-3),(1002,GetDate()-2),(1002,GetDate()-1);

SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES A.*, B.*
FROM @TABLE_A AS A
LEFT JOIN @TABLE_B AS B ON (B.OrderId = A.Orderid)
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.Orderid ORDER BY B.UpdateTime DESC)
```

But this has a disadvantage that it can't be ordered by extra fields (unless you put it in a sub-query).
However, this approach does have an advantage.
When a WHERE clause is added to limit the results, then this one it might be faster than the first query.  Since the second query wouldn't need to do a full table scan on TABLE_B.
Then again, if you put a WHERE clause in the sub-query of the first solution then it should also be fine I guess.

Comment: @rikyotei Thx for the rep. I've included an alternative with a snippet using table variables for easy testing.

Comment: it works fine thank you, i am looking for how to convert it to Linq so that i can use with EF. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_A AS ta
INNER JOIN TABLE_B AS tb ON ta.OrderId = tb.OrderId
ORDER BY tb.UpdateTime DESC
```

Comment: if do with this, one record in TABLE_A will link to multiple record of TABLE_B, but what i want is one order link to one order status which is latest. thanks